# Elementor pro custom opacity css animation

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I want to do a custom opacity animation in elementor pro. I tried to find some tutorials online as I am a beginner in this.

a reference that I want: https://www.anchour.com/

Here is what I found in the main css:

```
.hero.hero--home.video-in .hero-video-init, .hero.hero--home.video-in .hero-video-wrap:after, .hero.hero--home.video-in .hero-video-wrap:before {
opacity: 1;
```

}

```
.hero.hero--home .hero-video-wrap:after {
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 3s ease;
    transition-delay: 6.25s;
    z-index: 10;
}

.hero.hero--home .hero-video-wrap:after, .hero.hero--home .hero-video-wrap:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you already have and where do you fail to implement it? Do you already have a video file but trouble with the CSS?

Comment: I have only the video. I uploaded the video in the background. So I want a color from opacity 0 to 1 over the video before its ends. I am not sure if it is possible or not in elementor to add css opacity animation over the video background. Didn't find any proper solution.

Comment: So what is your <html> structure and your CSS code? Did you try the effect you want to achieve with opacity on another element already?

Comment: I am using elementor pro in wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

If I undestud it correctly, the "opacity" effect on their website its just white text on black video, then the video ends there're just black background and another background with higher z-index value has the opacity transition from 0 to 1.